# Selecting matching Dynamic field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, dynamic

I am trying to select a radio option in a form, and then have the matching dropdown option dynamically selected.
I.e., How do I select 'work' in the radio options, and dynamically automatically select 'work' in the dropdown? I am struggling with figuring out how to get this code to work. Ultimately, I would also like to change the colour of each option as it is selected.

Please see fiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/rs26nfk1/

```
<div class="container"> <p>

        <div contenteditable="true" id="myContent">

<form method="POST" action="..." onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<label for="new-task">Add</label><input id="new-task" type="text" placeholder="Task Name..."><br>
<label for="task-descr"></label><input id="task-descr" type="text" placeholder="Task Description..."><br>
<label>Date: <input type="text" size="12" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="startdate" id="startdate">
    <!--<small>(dd/mm/yyyy)</small>-->
    </label><br>
<input id="urgent" type="checkbox"><label for="urgent">Urgent</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="groceries" name="category" value="groceries">
<label for="groceries">Groceries</label>
<input type="radio" id="work" name="category" value="work">
<label for="work">Work</label>
<input type="radio" id="chores" name="category" value="other">
<label for="chores">Chores</label>
<input type="radio" id="finance" name="category" value="other">
<label for="finance">Finance</label>

<form>
    <br>
    Select your category:
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Groceries</option>
      <option>Work</option>
      <option>Chores</option>
      <option>Finance</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Click Me!">
    </form>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>

</form>

<!--Task Order-->

<button input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Click Me!">Add</button>

</form>
</p>
<h3>To Do</h3>
<ul id="incomplete-tasks">

</ul>

<h3>Completed</h3>
<ul id="completed-tasks">


</ul></div>

</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on('change', 'select[name="item_meta[work]"]', function () {
        var lookup_val = $(this).val();

        $("select[name='item_meta[mySelect]'] option").filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() === lookup_val;
        }).first().prop('selected', true).siblings().prop('selected', false);

        $("select[name='item_meta[mySelect]']").trigger({ type:'change', originalEvent:'custom' });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can check this
https://jsfiddle.net/bvh6c391/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a great deal too. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems your checking with radio button value with option values those values are not same now its fixed the above fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value of radio which is been checked then using that value *find* option which has that value and add `prop('selected', true);` to that option.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//onchange of input rado
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=category]', function() {
  var lookup_val = $(this).val(); //get  val
  //add slected
  $("select#mySelect").find("option:contains(" + lookup_val + ")").prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST" action="..." onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
  <label for="new-task">Add</label><input id="new-task" type="text" placeholder="Task Name..."><br>
  <label for="task-descr"></label><input id="task-descr" type="text" placeholder="Task Description..."><br>
  <label>Date: <input type="text" size="12" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="startdate" id="startdate">
    <!--<small>(dd/mm/yyyy)</small>-->
    </label><br>
  <input id="urgent" type="checkbox"><label for="urgent">Urgent</label><br>

  <input type="radio" id="groceries" name="category" value="Groceries">
  <label for="groceries">Groceries</label>
  <input type="radio" id="work" name="category" value="Work">
  <label for="work">Work</label>
  <input type="radio" id="chores" name="category" value="Chores">
  <label for="chores">Chores</label>
  <input type="radio" id="finance" name="category" value="Finance">
  <label for="finance">Finance</label>

  <form>
    <br> Select your category:
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Groceries</option>
      <option>Work</option>
      <option>Chores</option>
      <option>Finance</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Click Me!">
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I appreciate it greatly. I can't get it show up in the To Do list after I click the add button still, but will keep trying to figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: `I can't get it show up in the To Do list after I click the add button still, but will keep trying to figure that out..` please elaborate :) will help you in that as well .

Comment: Thank you! I am having trouble getting any of the form items to show up from the ADD section to the TO DO section after I click the add button. I used the variable var taskInput for the first one which works, but using var taskDescrInput and var startDateInput etc. for the other form options does not work. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: So, you mean inputs values are no showing after you click on add button ? you need to show all values of form inside incomplete area ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right, need all input values to show after clicking add button inside the incomplete To Do area

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6z0dkow/) i have done for date and radio input now you just need to do same for other . Create input and get values from input and add that in your dom.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I am trying to figure out how you have made it work for date and radio input, and will try to do the same for the rest! Hopefully I can make it work. It might take me awhile but hopefully I will get it. Thanks again for your help!